# Map collision function 2D game

Tags: c++, game-physics, collision

My player can move vertically, horizontally and diagonally. I'm having trouble writing a good diagonal collision function. My goal is to do the following: If a player moves diagonally and a collision occurs, then a player must continue to move along an axis (X or Y) that does not contain a collision, and not just return to the previous coordinates.

```
void Game::updateInput()
{
    dirX = 0;
    dirY = 0;

    if (GetKeyState('W') < 0) dirY = -1.f;
    if (GetKeyState('A') < 0) dirX = -1.f;
    if (GetKeyState('S') < 0) dirY =  1.f;  
    if (GetKeyState('D') < 0) dirX =  1.f;

    //speed reduction by 30% on each axis if the player moves diagonally
    if (dirX != 0.f && dirY != 0.f)
        player->move(dirX * 0.7f, dirY * 0.7f);
    else
        player->move(dirX, dirY);
}
```

```
for (auto& tile : mapTile) {
    Vectorf playerPos = player->getPos();
    if (playerPos.x < tile->coordinate_X + tileWidth &&
        playerPos.x + playerWidth > tile->coordinate_X &&
        playerPos.y < tile->coordinate_Y + tileHeight &&
        playerPos.y + playerHeight > tile->coordinate_Y) {

        Vectorf direction = player->getDirection();

        if (abs(direction.x) > abs(direction.y)) {
            // Horizontal movement is dominant
            player->setPosition(playerPos.x - direction.x, playerPos.y);
        }
        else if (abs(direction.y) > abs(direction.x)) {
            // Vertical movement is dominant
            player->setPosition(playerPos.x, playerPos.y - direction.y);
        }
        else {
            // Equal movement in both x and y directions -> choose one
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does my answer make sense to you?

Comment: I posted an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do on each collision is determine the dinstance your object has passed the collision point and then translate the object back that exact amount.

Do this for x and y independently.

This is what will make your character move along a wall even if they’re pressing the diagonal movement input.

**EDIT:** To get a precise simulation you’ll need to determine a `step size` in `time` that remains constant.

Each frame, calculate the `delta time` since the last frame.

Divide that time up into parts which are equal to your `step size`.

For each step that is available in a given frame, run the collision resolution scaled back by the `step size`.

Due to varying frame rate and a need for consistency in the simulation, you iterate the collision resolution as many times as you can in one frame, then wait for the next frame to continue the integration from where it left off. Once again, integrating as many steps as you can in that frame.

Some frames may have time to integrate 3 steps, some might have time for 2. But keeping the `step size` fixed is what keeps it smooth.

Breaking the movement up into smaller steps allows the simulation to prevent the multiple collision issue you’re talking about.

By moving things a tiny bit several times per frame, those other collisions will be handled smoothly since you’re not integrating an entire frame of time, which is variable, in one step.

Comment: I learned how to determine the depth of the intersection of two rectangles using the following algorithm "Separating Axis Theorem". The problem is that multiple collisions can occur. If go back along X and Y, counting their intersection depth, the sprite will stop moving. Need to select one axis. I am reading this article now. Can you take a look? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69339/2d-aabbs-and-resolving-multiple-collisions

Comment: I’ll post an update with more details but the gist is that for each frame, the collision simulation is run multiple times. The delta time between the frames is split into steps that are iterated over which smooth out the result.